# Referencing another project in .Net Core

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, asp.net-core-mvc

I have 6 projects in a blank solution. I just want to reference a project to another. I have `HomeController` in **Blog.Web** projects. I want to access another project's methods like `IOrganizationService` in **Blog.Services** projects. How can I use IOrganization's method in HomeController class? For clear insight, please see picture. 
[image]

Red marks show the errors....

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It *looks* like you've created everything as web sites, but I *suspect* that *most* of those projects should actually be class libraries (dlls), not sites. You might need to reset a few things!

You should be able to right-click on the Dependencies node to add a project reference:
[image]

or the project node:

[image]

then:[image]

Alternatively: edit the csproj and add a `<ProjectReference>` node:[image]

Comment: Сould you tell me how i can get this kind of reference through my C# code?

Comment: If you don't use Visual Studio, you can use the dotnet cli command `dotnet add reference <PROJECT_REFERENCES>`. Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-reference

Comment: how can i call classes/methods on the project that I referenced?

Comment: @ninja as long as the types/methods are `public`, then: simply by adding the right `using` directive, and/or just using the type names just like you do with any of the types you're getting from the *default* references

Comment: @MarcGravell I have a public class and a public method but it doesn't show when trying to create an instance or importing the namespace it via `using`.. the project I tried to reference was .net framework class library and .net standard library.

Comment: In addition you can specify the project to operate on: `dotnet add <TargetProject> reference <ProjectReference>`

Answer (score 16):

Edit your `MyProject.csproj` file. And add a new `ItemGroup` or add your package into an existing `ItemGroup`. Here's example:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Polly" Version="7.2.0" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SomeOtherProject\SomeOtherProject.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing this in Visual Studio Code, or you just want to use the CLI to accomplish the same task, you can also use the [dotnet CLI command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-reference) `dotnet add reference [relative_path_to_project]`.

So for example:
`dotnet add reference ../Api/MyApiProject.csproj`

Answer (score 0):

Simply upgrade your visual studio to 2022, it supports .net core up to 6.0, it is also compatible to older .net core sdk.