# Azure Devops build fails Warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

I'm trying to create a pipeline in Azure DevOps and I get compilation errors caused by a missing reference:

> [warning]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5):
>   Warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate
>   the assembly "ABC". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If
>   this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation
>   errors.

I have a VS2017 solution with 2 projects.

1. ABC which is the actual application
2. ABC.UnitTests where I added some unit tests (I'm using MSTest)

When I build the solution locally, I'm able to do a successful build with the following steps:

1. Build ABC project => ABC.dll is generated
2. Add reference in ABC.UnitTests proj to ABC.dll
3. Build the entire solution => build successful

The .cs file in ABC.UnitTests references the application in this way, and generates the warning above:

```
using ABC;
```

If I do a clean build where ABC.dll is deleted and then I do a build of the entire solution I get the same MSB3245 warning. So the issue is reproducible locally if the dll does not exist.

Then, when I upload the solution to Azure DevOps, I do the following steps.

1. Upload the solution from local VS2017 and a project is created in Azure
2. Build the project in Azure DevOps => reference issue reported

I have a YAML config file with name azure-pipelines.yml which references the hosted 2017 agent.

```
pool: vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'
```

Alternate flow:

1. Upload the solution from local VS2017 and a project is created in Azure
2. Comment out the reference to ABC.UnitTests project from the sln file
3. Create the pipeline => build successful.

Comment: this is how I reference the main project in the .csproj of the MSTest proj <ItemGroup> <Reference Include="ABC"> <HintPath>..\ABC\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\ABC.dll</HintPath> </Reference> </ItemGroup>

Comment: you should not refer the DLL like this. Instead, you should refer the Project directly like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44651771/7073340)

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thanks a lot for your help, I was stuck for ages.

Comment: I've expanded my comment as the answer, please accept it. so that it might help others too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't refer any DLL as you mentioned in the comment.

The proper way is to refer to as a project. This way the DLL takes care of itself during the build

Proper way is
`References` -> (Right Click) `Add References` -> From that using `Projects tab` you can choose the Project which is generating that DLL(assemblies)

You can refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44651629/referencing-another-project-in-net-core/44651771#44651771)