# Follow-up to Referencing another project in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm working on a new ASP.NET MVC Core which I'm writing using .NET 6. At this point I have my main MVC project I call BookFinder. Then I have a second project, which is a library project, named BookApi. I tried to find a way of using BookApi from BookFinder, but I haven't. I did find another post from 4 years ago named [Referencing another project in .Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44651629/referencing-another-project-in-net-core) which looked like it had hope, but I'm still not certain how to access BookApi from a Razor view in BookFinder. I've added a reference to BookApi in BookFinder. That reference makes it possible for me to then add a @using statement, but I don't know how to get to a GetBooksByAuthor() method in BookApi from BookFinder. (GetBooksByAuthor() is declared public static in BookApi.) I've tried adding some code to the Razor view, but it doesn't let me get to GetBooksByAuthor() method of BookApi. Here's what I've got so far

```html
@using BookApi  @*First added a reference to this library project*@


@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Search by author";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Search by book author</h1>
</div>
```

And here's a snippet from my Solution Explorer from Vs 2022:

[image]

Comment: If it is an API project then you need to consume it using HttpClient. Please refer to the docs [Microsoft docs HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0)

Comment: *"but I'm still not certain how to access `BookApi` from a Razor view in `BookFinder`"* - is that `BookApi` class and `GetBooksByAuthor` are public? is `BookApi` a static class? if yes to both question, you can do `BookApi.GetBooksByAuthor`. if the last one is wrong, you will need to create an instance of `BookApi`. however, all we can say are just guess work (given we dont know how `BookApi` looks like).

Comment: Do you set the static method in  a static class?

Comment: I think you could try to package your class library  then install it in your mvc project through Nuget

Comment: can you please share your project somehow ?
Lib which framework is using ?

Comment: @BagusTesa, thank you, for asking the question that you did. I made the GetBooksByAuthor() method static but left the BookApi as a regular class. I've changed that and made the BookApi class also static. BTW, I tried to vote up your suggestion/question, but Stack Overflow won't let me do that, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try `@BookApi.GetBooksByAuthor("")` in your view

In my case:[image]